# Does declaring Func<> in List.ForEach causing memory leak and increase process memory?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, func

I know I shouldn't be declaring `Func<>` inside the `foreach`, but I want to know does this C# code increase the process memory and cause a memory leak?

```cs
class Foo {
    int[] FooA = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    string result = "";
    void myMethod() {
        FooA.ToList().ForEach(a => {
            Func<int, string> myFunc = myFuncVar => $"Value: {myFuncVar}\n";
            result += myFunc(a);
        });
        MessageBox.Show(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: There won't be memory leak because `myFunc` doesn't leave scope and nobody references it. In given case `myFunc` will be collected in gen0 (most frequent collections), so memory overhead is minimal

Comment: @JL0PD In which you means if I call `myMethod()` in other methods, there won't be any memory leak?

Comment: What is your reasoning for "I shouldn't declaring `Func<>` inside the `foreach`"? I don't know of one, so wondering... (clearly in this particular case it is useless, but it is completely expected that [MCVE] strictly demonstrate the problem and do not include extra code as shown in this post... so you likely have other reasons)

Comment: @TCPW01, yes. But if you want exactly that code it better to use `string.Join`

Comment: Managed frameworks like .NET don't have memory leaks per se. I.e. you could "pack rat" and stuff a bunch of references you'll never use again somewhere and waste memory that way. But you'll never lose track of a reference to a memory block that the memory manager can't get rid of.

Comment: If you are worried about overhead and allocations and whatnot, avoid the use of ToList+ForEach and use a for/foreach loop on the original and don't allocate a list just so you can call ForEach (method). There's also better ways to do this. `string.Join("\n", FooA.Select(c => $"Value: {c}"))` or `var sb=new StringBuilder(); foreach(var c in FooA) sb.AppendFormat("Value: {0}\n", c); sb.Length -= 1; var result = sb.ToString();` or a pleathorea of different ways that don't involving allocating a list/backing array and a bunch of extra delegates and closures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's helpful to use a disassembly tool like [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQAwAIpwHQBkCWAdgI4Dcys6AYgPY3IDey6L6RALgNoC61dAgugC86BujgAadDCkBmKQBZ0AX3JJWmOBgBOAUwDOAVwA27YegBEFtc1ZQlAWwCeAWV3sAFjWAAKAJS2LEzqGqy0NPzYACo0BPrs/ti02gCiAIYAxh4+acIAfIGhwaElmACsADwcUlioeejOUGXmjWUAamna+egAJBYdxoa6IKKtHdrKADqE1oWl6HpGpuhgIq05fmrzypuFysjKQA==);

```cs
// trim
internal class Foo
{
    [Serializable]
    [CompilerGenerated]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly <>c <>9 = new <>c();

        public static Func<int, string> <>9__2_1;

        internal string <myMethod>b__2_1(int myFuncVar)
        {
            return string.Format("Value: {0}\n", myFuncVar);
        }
    }

    private int[] FooA;

    private string result;

    private void myMethod()
    {
        Enumerable.ToList(FooA).ForEach(new Action<int>(<myMethod>b__2_0));
    }

    public Foo()
    {
        int[] array = new int[4];
        RuntimeHelpers.InitializeArray(array, (RuntimeFieldHandle)/*OpCode not supported: LdMemberToken*/);
        FooA = array;
        result = "";
        base..ctor();
    }

    [CompilerGenerated]
    private void <myMethod>b__2_0(int a)
    {
        Func<int, string> func = <>c.<>9__2_1 ?? (<>c.<>9__2_1 = new Func<int, string>(<>c.<>9.<myMethod>b__2_1));
        result += func(a);
    }
}
// trim
```

You can see that your lambda (`myFuncVar => $"Value: {myFuncVar}\n";`) has been promoted to a method (`<myMethod>b__2_1`) on a singleton instance (`<>c.<>9`). With a lazily initialised static cache of the Func delegate (`<>c.<>9__2_1`).

So no, at least in this case, there's actually no per iteration allocation going on here.

The compiler can prove that your lambda does not need a reference to a local variable, nor any other instance field. Even though the variable you assign that lambda to has local scope and lifetime, the lambda itself can be promoted to a static lifetime. Similar to the way string literals are assigned to variables, but the string object has a static lifetime.